# set a cookie clicking a menu link in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies

I need to register a cookie when a specific menu link is clicked (I use this cookie to redirect a mobile user from the mobile version of the site to the desktop version).
In a non WP site I just use the `onclick` attribute to achieve this, like in this example:

```
<script>
function setupCookie() {
    document.cookie = "desktop=true;domain=.mysite.com";
}
</script>

    <a href="mysite.com" onclick="setupCookie();"> Desktop version </a>
```

But I'm having trouble doing this in Wordpress due to how the menus are handled, the HTML structure is this (I added the class `desktop-redirect` using the custom CSS WP menu field).

```
<li class="desktop-redirect menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1261">

<a href="mysite.com">Desktop version</a>

</li>
```

I've tried something like this:

```
function setupCookie() {
        document.cookie = "desktop=true;domain=.mysite.com";
    }
    element.addEventListener("click", setupCookie(),false);
    var element = document.getElementsByClassname("desktop-redirect")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

But it doesn't work (the `desktop-redirect` class is unique to that `li` element).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your element.addEventListener come after you declare the variable?

Comment: I used another question as reference where they used that order, however even if i define the element var before the element.addEventListener it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setupCookie() {
    document.cookie = "desktop=true;domain=.mysite.com";
}
document.getElementsByClassName("desktop-redirect")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", setupCookie);
```

Note that your getElementsByClassName did not capitalize the "N" in name... not sure if that is your code, or a typo, but that is one issue.  Also, you leave out the () in the function call.

Comment: it doesn't work unfortunately, looking at the console i see this error "TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined"

Comment: if it's undefined, then you aren't finding any elements with the said class name.  Try to set a variable to contain document.getElementsByClassName("desktop-redirect") and then push that to the console to see what the result is.  Sounds like the error has more to do with finding the actual element on the page!